# No 'Access-Control-Cross-Origin' header, but still receiving document

Tags: javascript

I am using a Control By Web device (http://www.controlbyweb.com/webrelay/webrelay_users_manual.pdf) to enable and disable a relay. I am attempting to create my own site that will use their API to control the device. This involves doing GET requests to the relay.

I understand the concept of CORS, and why I am not able to do a CORS request to the web server on the relay (it does not have Access-Control-Allow-Origin header).

My confusion is that when I look in the Network tab of the developer tools I can see a status of 200 for the document and actually view the returned XML. On top of that, I can issue GET commands with parameters to actually control the relay.

Can anyone explain why I have access to the document from the developer tools, but I am still seeing an exception in the console?

Comment: What's the domain of your API server and the domain of the API you are calling? Can you share the screenshot of network tab?

Comment: It seems that you're not understanding the [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) concept yet. External server **must** respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Otherwise your request is failed.

Comment: @hindmost I am expecting it to fail. That is my question. I am getting an exception in the console, but my network tab has a status code of 200 for the document and I am able to view the document. Those two things are not consistent.

Comment: @YuVi An example would be 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2.

Comment: What you have access to the remote document from the developer tools has **no relation** to CORS (since here is not security issues). CORS is only applicable to JS scripts, not to developer tools which are part of browser.

Comment: @hindmost Why should the request fail? Both the request and response will work. Only when the client script tries to access the returned data from a different origin the browser will intervene with a CORS error - if the server doesn't allow that origin (or all)

Comment: @Andreas Obviously I meant the cross-origin request which is the OP's case (_External server must..._)

Comment: Thank you! That was my misconception. I thought even having access to the script in the developer tools was a security issue.